# Ensemble Method using XGBoost and RotationForest python

Tags: python, ensemble-modeling

How can I create an ensemble model using `XGBoost` and `Rotation Forest` in Python?

Comment: This is rather too general, Im not sure why you are looking into things like https://github.com/tmadl/sklearn-random-rotation-ensembles to combine with XGboost, if this is what needed.